# show record in between field in mysql not using sub query

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

i want the field nilai_kredit to top at between filed nilai_kredit, if the acct_no is same, but i don't want to use sub query because is slowly

```
SELECT
  a.acct_no,
  IF (a.kode = 'D', SUM(a.nilai), 0) AS nilai_debet,
  IF (a.kode = 'K', SUM(a.nilai), 0) AS nilai_kredit 
FROM
  tr2015 a
INNER JOIN acct2015 b
  ON a.acct_no = b.acct_no AND b.sub='AP'
WHERE a.tgl LIKE '2015-01%'AND a.hps <> '*'
GROUP BY a.acct_no,a.kode
```

[this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VI7I.jpg)

Comment: remove `a.kode` from `GROUP BY` then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  a.acct_no,
  SUM(IF(a.kode = 'D', a.nilai, 0)) AS nilai_debet,
  SUM(IF(a.kode = 'K', a.nilai, 0)) AS nilai_kredit 
FROM
  tr2015 a
INNER JOIN acct2015 b
  ON a.acct_no = b.acct_no AND b.sub='AP'
WHERE a.tgl LIKE '2015-01%'AND a.hps <> '*'
GROUP BY a.acct_no
```

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS nilai_debet,
  SUM(IF (a.kode = 'K', a.nilai, 0) AS nilai_kredit 
FROM
 tr' at line 3